Getting issue for selection dynamic slot duration in fullcalander
I want to display slot duration dynamically for day because we are using fullcalander for booking the volleyball court bases on hours like 10 to 23. 
I want to set the slot duration for 10 to 03:00 for 1 hour, 03 to 23 of 1:30 based on different prices but I am not  able to do this.  
Use case is this: because when we are using the select range hook there is time mismatching for start time and end time. Due to that I am not able to create an event.
In the second image I am clicking into 19:00 to 20:30 slot but with select range I was getting 18:00 to 19:00 which is incorrect.


I want to know how to fix this slot duration issue.
  <Calendar
          schedulerLicenseKey="CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives"

          initialView={view}
          dayMaxEventRows={3}
          snapDuration="01:00:00"
          slotLabelFormat={{ month:"long"}}
          defaultRangeSeparator="to"
          select={onSelectRange}
          aspectRatio={3}
          datesSet={handleDatesSet} // Set custom keys when dates are set
          dateClick={handleDateClick} // Handle click on dates
          longPressDelay={1}
          resourceAreaWidth={smUp?150:100}
          height={smUp?dummyResources.length*65:dummyResources.length*60}
          showNonCurrentDates={false}
          selectMirror
          slotMinutes= {5}
          eventDrop={arg => {
            onDropEvent(arg, updateEvent);
          }}
          eventResize={arg => {
            onResizeEvent(arg, updateEvent);
          }}
          slotDuration="01:00:00"

          slotMinTime="10:00:00"
          slotMaxTime="23:00:00"
          slotLabelContent={arg=>slotGenerator.next().value?.time}
          viewDidMount={arg => {
            console.log(arg.view.calendar,'mew------------------------------------------------')
          }}
          resourcesInitiallyExpanded
          initialResources={dummyResources}
          resourceLabelContent={({ resource }) => resource.title}
          plugins={[
            listPlugin,
            dayGridPlugin,
            timelinePlugin,
            timeGridPlugin,
            resourceTimelinePlugin,
            resourceTimeGridPlugin,
            interactionPlugin,
          ]}
        />


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

i have added the code pleae check

What is slotGenerator and what does it do? It seems to me that you're trying to create slots of different sizes in the same timeline. FullCalendar does not support this. So while you may have changed the label in the slot heading to say "19:00-20:30", that doesn't mean that fullCalendar thinks the slot is 1.5 hours long. You told fullCalendar that slots are 1 hour long, so when you select that slot, it will tell you that  19:00-20:00 was selected, which is true as far as how fullCalendar works and understands the grid it's created.

So I don't think it's actually possible to do it this way. A better approach would be to have slotDuration of 30 minutes. Then in the select process you can have extra validation to check the time of day, and ensure that the user only selects 1-hour events in the first part of the day, and 1.5-hour events in the later part of the day. You can make it refuse to create anything for selections which aren't that size, if you like. Or you can do something like alter the end time before you pass it to your dialog box. So there are different possible approaches, but your current one won't work.
